# How to stop expanding html elements from scrolling the page?

Tags: html, css

I have an div which contains some text which has it's opacity set to 0 and visibility set to hidden, but when another element is clicked, the opacity goes to 1 and the visibility is visible, but this causes the page to scroll a small amount rather than the expanded content just pushing the content below it down and making the page longer. How can I solve this?

Comment: please add code snippet or jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: Why goes the opacity to 1? Do you want this? 

When you use `visibility: hidden`, you hide something, but it still takes his physical space.

If you don't want that, you can use `display:none` instead of visibility

Comment: Please follow this guidance here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  As you have no code of your own, you should add some per site guidlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element's visibility is set to hidden the element is still there its just transparent. But the extra space will stay. 
By changing `visibility: hidden` to `display: none` the element is totally hidden and won't take extra space.
Check this post for a better explanation: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/10347490)